# Custom JLabel class breaks positioning of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've created a class extending JLabel, as normally it is not antialiased. But, when i use it, whole positioning of JLabel is broken. How is that possible?
Here's the code for the class:

```
private class AntialiasedJLabel extends JLabel{

    public AntialiasedJLabel(){}

    public AntialiasedJLabel(String name){
        this.setText(name);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawString(getText(),getX(),getY());
    }
}
```

Here's the result using normal JLabel:
[image]

And here using AntialiasedJLabel:
[image]

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do the custom painting yourself. Instead do:

```
Graphics g2 = g.create();
g2.setRenderingHint(...);

super.paintComponent(g2);

g2.dispose();
```

Comment: That only causes text to be drawn twice (A combination of both cases i've shown). Since my method generally redraws everything, there is no need for super invoking.

Comment: @TheMorfeus Sorry, I was in the middle of editing the answer when I rechecked your code.

Comment: Oh, it's okay, but there is still no effect using your method :/

Comment: @TheMorfeusm, then post your `SSCCE` (like you were asked to do in your last posting) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try setting KEY_ANTIALIASING as well as KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING. JLabel probably draws its label with a GlyphVector (a Shape) which text antialias probably has no effect on.

Comment: @Radiodef `getX`/`getY` refer to the position of the label within it's parent context, painting is always done from the perspective of `0x0` being the top, left corner of the component.  `JLabel` already does a very good job of painting text, why would you want to stop it.  Instead, as camickr as shown, simply provide additional hints to the `Graphics` context to improve the rendering output...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't suggest camickr's solution was wrong. If JLabel draws a GlyphVector text antialiasing won't have an effect on it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, camickr's solution doesnt seem to work properly though.

Comment: @TheMorfeus, Define "properly". You still haven't posted a SSCCE like you have been asked to do multiple times. So we can't guess what you are talking about.

Comment: I do not even understand properly what SSCCE is, and i gave up on the error and went without antialiasing anyway.

Comment: @TheMorfeus, what don't you understand about SSCCE? You have been given a link to the web page that explains what it is. What part about the link don't you understand. Again we can't help if you don't give us the information. Same as with your question. If you can't define what you mean by "properly" we can't help. That is why a SSCCE is important because then we can see what you are talking about when we execute the code.